# How find stochastic logarithm of $B^2(t)+1$.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Find the stochastic logarithm of $B^2(t)+1$.
I know that for find stochastic logarithm According to Theorem we must use the The following formula $$X(t)=\mathcal L(U)(t)= \ln(\frac{U(t)}{U(0)})+\int_{0}^{t} \frac{d[U,U](t)}{2U^2(t)} $$

I start and if $U(t)=B^2(t)+1$ Then $dU(t)=dt+2B(t)dB(t)$ and $d[U,U](t)=4 B^2(t)dt$

and my problem is I cannot get a close form or I cannot Calculate the integral.

thanks for help

Comment: I am confused - why do you calculate the stochastic logarithm of $e^{B(t)}$ if you want to find the stochastic logarithm of $B^2(t)+1$...?

Comment: @saz.No my mean is that I can use this formula and in the case $B^2(t)+1$ I have problem.

Comment: So where are you stuck? Did you calculate the quadratic variation $d[U,U](t)$ for $U_t := B(t)^2+1$? (And note that you can in general not expect to find an explicit formula for the stochastic logarithm.)

Comment: @saz. I edit the question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be expected to note that
$$
X_t=\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm dU_s}{U_s}=2\int_0^t\frac{B_s}{B_s^2+1}\mathrm dB_s+\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm ds}{B_s^2+1}.
$$

Comment: @saz Thanks for the edit (how careless of me...).

Comment: ... but this formula doesn't help to get a closed form for $X_t$, does it? (That's what the OP is asking for, I believe.)

Comment: @saz Nope. By the way, how to define "closed form" here (or "Calculate the integral")? If "closed form" refers to $X_t=F(B_t,t)$, I see no hope.

Comment: Yeah, of course, the usual question (but yes, in fact I call an representation of the form $X_t=F(B_t,t)$ "closed form"). Simply wasn't sure whether I missed something obvious :).

Comment: @saz No problem, always a pleasure to check with you that one or the other is not misled. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I happen to meet this problem as Exercise 5.8 on Fima C. Klebaner's *Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications (3ed)*.

Just want to make an observation: the two results -- computed directly by definition and by the formula mentioned in the question -- are indeed the same.

On one hand, we may directly compute by definition. That is Did's answer:

$$X(t)=\mathcal L(U)(t)=\int_0^t\frac{\mathrm dU(s)}{U(s)}=\int_0^t\frac{2B(s)}{B(s)^2+1}\mathrm dB(s)+\int_0^t\frac{1}{B(s)^2+1}\mathrm ds$$

On the other hand, we may use the formula mentioned in the question, which in this case yields

$$
X(t)=\mathcal L(U)(t)= \ln(B^2(t)+1) \ +\int_{0}^{t} \frac{2B^2(s)}{[B^2(s)+1]^2}\mathrm ds
$$

The two results are indeed the same, which can be seen if we take the differential of $\ln(B^2(t)+1)$ by Ito's formula, which is

$$
\mathrm d\ln(B^2(t)+1) = \frac{2B(s)}{B^2(s)+1}\mathrm dB(s) + \frac{1-B^2(s)}{[B^2(s)+1]^2}\mathrm ds
$$

Note that after combining the $\mathrm ds$ terms,
$$
\frac{1-B^2(s)}{[B^2(s)+1]^2} + \frac{2B^2(s)}{[B^2(s)+1]^2} = \frac{B^2(s)+1}{[B^2(s)+1]^2} =  \frac{1}{B^2(s)+1} 
$$

So both the terms on $\mathrm dB(s)$ and $\mathrm ds$ are the same for the two formulae.